# How to install GRUB on RAID6 with Ubuntu Server 16.04.1?

Tags: server, system-installation, raid, mdadm, xfs

The hardware I am using uses a "BIOS legacy" boot schema, so no UEFI stuff is involved.

My initial setup has 4 SAS disks from which I created a raid6 device (md0).

Then I partitioned it into md0p1 for / and md0p5 for /home and formatted these in XFS. For the latter I have also used LVM2, but I am pretty sure this is irrelevant.

Everything has been done with the Ubuntu Server 16.04.1 installer.

At the end, the system won't boot leaving me with a grub prompt saying it cannot find the device by UUID.

I think the installer is not RAID-aware, but it could be I did something wrong.

Any hint?

P.S.
It is a server: please don't suggest to install GUI-based software!